# Does Steam have an API for sales data?

Tags: steam, steamworks, api

I go to the Steamworks website to see data about my game, change its page, see sales numbers, etc. Is there a way I can download this data into my own visualization setup so it is easier for me to view up to data information. I am mostly interested in getting page view, sales, and wishlist data so I can overlay that with marketing events, sales, etc in my own software.

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.steamapis.com/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this spot in the [Steamworks Quick Tips - UTM Analytics on Steam video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-qmYY69kqI&list=PLckFgM6dUP2ioUbjUyol6SWAdBPlEvN9e&index=10&t=328s) you can see an option in the lower right corner for downloading UTM data as a CSV:

[image: screen cap from video]

Documentation for UTM is available [here](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/marketing/utm_analytics).

The [Sales & Activations Reports portal docs](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/finance/payments_salesreporting) and the [Wishlist Reporting docs](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/marketing/wishlist/reporting) also mention CSV options.

If you can't find what you're after digging through the CSVs, searching the docs and browsing their [developer videos](Official Group for Steamworks Development Support), you'll probably need to ask in the [Steamworks Development Support Group](https://steamcommunity.com/groups/steamworks) or contact
a Valve developer support specialist.